# got error for set map path in visual studio code

Tags: python

I'm try to set path for map using this line

```
world.save('maps_htmls/world_empty.html')
```

and i got error :-

```
File "e:\Monty Python Project\ALL TASK\Task\Individual programming project.py", line 35, in <module>
    world.save('../maps_htmls/world_empty.html')
  File "C:\Users\singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 164, in save
    fid = open(outfile, 'wb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../maps_htmls/world_empty.html'
```

Comment: ../maps_htmls  directory doesn't exist. you should create it. you can use os.mkdir, for example.

Comment: actually, it is exist but i don't know how to set path for it.

Comment: the file root is >    E:\Monty Python Project\ALL TASK\Task\1

Comment: where does maps_htmls exist? can you specify path?

Comment: If you're confident your file exists, try passing an absolute path instead of a relatively path to the `save` method. Also, why does the error say `'../maps_htm...'`, so going up one directory, when you didn't specify this in your method call?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is your directory structure?